# regex Redirect subdirectories in htaccess , but DONT redirect the parent directory index itself

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Hello I am trying to 301 redirect any and all subdirectories of a parent directory , **but NOT have the parent directory index itself be redirected**

Here's what I currently have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parent/(.*) /newtoplevel/parent/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

The above code seems to work fine, but unfortunately for my use it also redirects the original parent index to the new. For example if I load http://example.com/parent/ it will redirect to http://example.com/newtoplevel/parent/ **which is NOT what I need**...

I only want the various /parent/subdirectory/ to redirect to /newtoplevel/parent/subdirectory

While making sure that /parent/index.html ( http://example.com/parent/ ) does NOT redirect

Comment: Does my post solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the subdirectories (`parent/.../`) of `parent` to be redirected (and keeping the sub-trees as-is) then you should use the following regex:

```
^parent/(.+/.+)
```

Tested on **regex101**: https://regex101.com/r/gv6ZUf/4

Comment: ok I tried `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parent/(.+/.+) /newtoplevel/parent/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`  but nothing is redirecting at all